# How can i add toggle button in ASP.NET MVC CORE and take data back side?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

How can I add a toggle button in ASP.NET MVC CORE and take data backside?

I want this button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKNkK.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by toggle button, but here is example how to get data from View to backside.

**Example for get method:**

*View:*

```
<form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Admin" method="get">
    <div>
        <label>@T["Data:"]</label>
        <input asp-for="Data" type="number" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">@T["Get data"]</button>
</form>
```

*AdminController:* *(for example)*

```
public IActionResult Index(int data)
{
   //DO WORK 
}
```